# PostgreSQL query on jsonb column is not using indexes

Tags: postgresql, index, json

I have the following table and indexes where all those indexes were created to try and find a solution to my issue:

```
create table persistent_events
(
    "notificationId"                       text         not null
        constraint persistent_events_pkey
            primary key,
    payload                                bytea        not null,
    notification                           jsonb
);


create index metadatadescriptionidx
    on persistent_events (((notification -> 'metadata'::text) ->> 'description'::text));

create index metadataidx
    on persistent_events ((notification ->> 'metadata'::text));

create index metadataidxgin
    on persistent_events using gin ((notification -> 'metadata'::text));

create index metadatadescriptionidxgin
    on persistent_events (((notification -> 'metadata'::text) -> 'description'::text));

create index metadataidx2
    on persistent_events ((notification -> 'metadata'::text));

create index metadatadescriptionidx2
    on persistent_events (((notification -> 'metadata'::text) -> 'description'::text));

create index metadataidx3
    on persistent_events (jsonb_extract_path(notification, VARIADIC ARRAY ['metadata'::text]));

create index metadatadescriptionidx4
    on persistent_events ((jsonb_extract_path(notification, VARIADIC ARRAY ['metadata'::text]) -> 'description'::text));

create index metadatadescriptionidx3
    on persistent_events ((jsonb_extract_path(notification, VARIADIC ARRAY ['metadata'::text]) ->>
                           'description'::text));
```

The data stored in the notification column is like the following, but the content of notificationData varies a lot.

```
{
    "metadata":
    {
        "description": "Test event",
        "notificationId": "5eaf73ac-c0b1-4e39-86cc-d5cf9f5f33190e"
    },
    "notificationData":
    {
        "attributesChangeInfo":
        [
            {
                "newValue": "host",
                "oldValue": "localhost",
                "attributeName": "something"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

If I query with the following statement everything works fine:

```
SELECT notification, payload
FROM persistent_events
WHERE ((notification->'metadata'->>'description' = 'Test event'));
```

The execution plan is the following and it is using the indexes as expected:

```
Bitmap Heap Scan on persistent_events  (cost=93.12..15578.79 rows=4735 width=549) (actual time=2.076..2.078 rows=2 loops=1)
  Recheck Cond: (((notification -> 'metadata'::text) ->> 'description'::text) = 'Test event'::text)
  Heap Blocks: exact=1
  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on metadatadescriptionidx  (cost=0.00..91.94 rows=4735 width=0) (actual time=0.845..0.846 rows=2 loops=1)
        Index Cond: (((notification -> 'metadata'::text) ->> 'description'::text) = 'Test event'::text)
Planning Time: 16.939 ms
Execution Time: 2.177 ms
```

If I write it with the following statement using jsonb_extract_path it is not using the indexes:

```
SELECT notification, payload
FROM persistent_events,
     jsonb_extract_path(notification, 'metadata') metadata0
WHERE ((metadata0->>'description' = 'Test event'));
```

Plan:

```
Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..127054.49 rows=947014 width=549) (actual time=74.733..2566.834 rows=2 loops=1)
  ->  Seq Scan on persistent_events  (cost=0.00..103379.14 rows=947014 width=549) (actual time=0.019..1457.983 rows=947014 loops=1)
  ->  Function Scan on jsonb_extract_path metadata0  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=0 loops=947014)
        Filter: ((metadata0 ->> 'description'::text) = 'Test event'::text)
        Rows Removed by Filter: 1
Planning Time: 0.849 ms
JIT:
  Functions: 6
"  Options: Inlining false, Optimization false, Expressions true, Deforming true"
"  Timing: Generation 1.069 ms, Inlining 0.000 ms, Optimization 8.907 ms, Emission 63.872 ms, Total 73.849 ms"
Execution Time: 2772.180 ms
```

The problem is that I need to write most queries using jsonb_extract_path and jsonb_array_elements as the json contains different arrays that I need to filter on. Is there any way to have PostgreSQL use the indexes even if I use those two functions?

Here's another example using an array:

```
SELECT notification, payload
FROM persistent_events,
     jsonb_extract_path(notification, 'notificationData') notificationData0,
     jsonb_array_elements(notificationData0->'attributesChangeInfo') attributesChangeInfo0
WHERE ((attributesChangeInfo0->>'newValue' = 'host'));
```

How would you rewrite this to exploit the indexes?

Comment: Using a function on a column is an efficient means to avoid using an index.  If you want to have a better chance at using it, your where clause should match the index formula.  BTW, json is not meant to be efficient.

Comment: I understand your point. I can match the clause as long as I do not need to get the elements inside an array. At that point I don't know how to express that I want every single object in the array as a row without using those functions ;)

Comment: In the second query, why don't you use the where clause from the first?

Comment: jsonb_extract_path is not a set returning function, so using at as a table in a FROM is just strange.  Please show an example of what you want to do that is **not** trivially re-writable into something you already know how to do.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille I've added an example of a query that goes through an array that I can't seem to be able to rewrite in a way to exploit the indexes

Comment: Would this be of any help?  https://bitnine.net/blog-postgresql/postgresql-internals-jsonb-type-and-its-indexes/  or https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html#JSON-INDEXING